# How to import 'gz'( which already exported into server ) file into mysql database using php code?

Tags: php, mysql, import

Please help me to find out code for importing 'gz'file( which already exported into server using php code)  into mysql database using php code.
here i need only import code ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need the PHP function **readgzfile()**

If you provide more detail, I'll try to ...er... provide more detail :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Snippet.

```
$srcName='1.gz';
$dstName='2.txt'
$sfp = gzopen($srcName, "rb");
$fp = fopen($dstName, "w");

while ($string = gzread($sfp, 4096)) {
     fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));
}
gzclose($sfp);
fclose($fp);
```

after extract with this class you can use simple below code to execute.

```
mysql_query(file_get_contents("2.txt"));
```

Comment: Why have you limited the read length in gzread? If his compressed files >4096 he'll have corruption.

Comment: you can change this ;) its example for you